# Composite Key in Access 2016

Tags: composite-primary-key, ms-access-2016

I'm creating those auxiliary tables, that stores two foreing keys, for a N:N relationship.

I dont want to create another field just for primary key. I want to use both of them as PK.

If a mark both fields as NEEDED and EXCLUSIVE, they'll meet all PK requirements?

Answer (score 0):

No. What you need is to create a *unique index* holding the two fields, then mark this as the *Primary Key*.

Comment: I found it. Instructions: 1) Select your table; 2) Click on Design View button; 3) Select the fields that will be part of the composite key; 4) Click on Primary Key Button.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to solve this problem without using auxiliary table is Lookup fields.

You limit the possible values to a list or a table and those will appear in a dropbox.

And with just a check box in the wizard, you now have a multiple value field.

1) Select your table

2) Select design view mode

3) Select "Lookup Assistance", in the Data Type colunm of the field you want to change.

4) Follow the wizard.

Hint, its better to get the values from a table than from a non-structured list.

It'll ease future changes or the insertion of new values.